# NSArrayController observing its content count

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

How do I observe the array controller's count?

What I've tried so far:

```
    //...
    self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.arrayController = [[NSArrayController alloc] initWithContent:self.array];

    [self.arrayController addObserver:self
                                  forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects"
                                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                                     context:@"self.array"];


    [self.array addObject:@"anoop"];
    [self.array addObject:@"amit"];


    NSLog(@"%ld", [self.arrayController.content count] );

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if( object == self.arrayController) {
           ...
    }
}
```

My actual requirement is to observe the array count, but since Array is not KVO compliant, I can't do it. Also I do not want to subclass Array and just add one array property to it as shown in other answers.  And then I thought of observing array controller.

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In order to observe the count of `arrangedObjects`, you must specify a *collection operator* in your key path. The one you want to use is `@count`.

So instead of using:

```
arrangedObjects
```

you should be using

```
arrangedObjects.@count
```